# Using OnItemClickListener with Firebase

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having trouble finding out how to do something simple. I'm populating a ListView in android with a custom ArrayAdapter. I use this code to populate the listview:

```
mRouteListener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Route route = dataSnapshot.getValue(Route.class);
                adapter.add(route);
            }
```

This works. I'm trying to set an OnItemClickListener to the items in my listview like so:

```
 ListView routeListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Find and set empty view on the ListView, so that it only shows when the list has 0 items.
        View emptyView = findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
        routeListView.setEmptyView(emptyView);

        ArrayList<Route> routeList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new RouteAdapter(this, routeList);
        // may want to change this to FirebaseAdapter

        routeListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        routeListView.setOnItemClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Wall10Activity.this, SingleRouteActivity.class);
                // I want to start a new activity then query the db to populate the information.
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

What I can't figure out is how to query the database from the SingleRoute.class with all the data from the view they clicked on.  I don't have access to the randomly generated key. It's stored like so:

```
{

  "routes" : {

    "-KcyQUzuVogjq3yPnr9u" : {

      "color" : 0,

      "grade" : 10,

      "name" : "YELLOW"

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Didnt really get your question , you have data mapped to Route class  and added to adapter ..what does `What I can't figure out is how to query the database from the SingleRoute.class` mean here ??

Comment: Sorry I could have been more clear. I have a list view with information from objects in my database. When i click on a view I want to launch a new activity that I can populate with more detailed information contained in the database object.

Comment: Then in onClick while doing ` startActivity(i);` you can pass `route-> routelist.get(position)` which contains detailed information  object with intent and access that in activity.

Comment: @RenuYadav hey thanks! I actually didn't know you can pass custom objects in an intent. Looks like you just have to implement a specific interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the Firebase SDK information you of a new child, it gives you a `DataSnapshot`, which contains a `getKey()` and a `getValue()`. You're also passed a `previousKey`, which is called `s` in your code.

```
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousKey) {
  Route route = dataSnapshot.getValue(Route.class);
  adapter.add(route);
}
```

Your code ignore the `getKey()` and the `previousKey` and only takes the `getValue()` of the snapshot for the adapter. This loss of information makes it impossible to do certain things down the line, such as mapping the position of an item that was clicked on back to the key of the underlying database node.

To allows this backwards mapping, you must keep both the key and the value of the snapshot in the adapter. The exact implementation is up to you, but you'd invoke it like:

```
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousKey) {
  Route route = dataSnapshot.getValue(Route.class);
  adapter.add(dataSnapshot.getKey(), route);
}
```

You really should not ignore `previousKey`, as this may contain important information about where the item should be displayed in the list. While initially it indeed is quite common to have an append-only list, this often changes over time. To ensure the adapter has all the information it needs to insert the item in the correct spot and to map back from a position to a key:

```
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousKey) {
  Route route = dataSnapshot.getValue(Route.class);
  adapter.add(dataSnapshot.getKey(), route, previousKey);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will work with the code, but it feels like the right track. I'm not sure the best implementation, but i'm going to try creating a simple wrapper class for Route that includes the key and Route and pass that to the adapter. THen I will send the key in the intent to my SingleRouteActivity and query the database there. THanks! Btw your tutorial on udacity is great.